# PHP Merging Array with Row of Data

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to figure out and clarify what the following line of code does. The line takes a row of imported and sets it equal to an array of 2 merged arrays. Does this include the row of imported data into the `mergedArrays`?

```
$arrayOfData[$rowNumber] = $mergedArrays;
```

Comment: You could write up a little test file and find out for yourself. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running my own test script, I found out that the `$arrayOfData[$rowNumber]` is having values added to it from the merged arrays. `$rowNumber` is incrementing, so values are being added to each row until no rows are left. Any `keys` in `$arrayOfData` with the same key name will have their `values` replaced if they're a string. Values will append if they're integers.